# meteor run ios-device keeps serving old version

Tags: meteor

Does `meteor run ios-device` not build from scratch every time you run it? While `meteor run ios` serves the latest code, `ios-device` seems to serve the code that was built before. I have checked documents but haven't found anything related.

Comment: Hi Maximus - we seem to be getting the same issue - did you ever resolve this?! It's really strange....!!

Answer (score 0):

Are you building against a server other than your local server (i.e. something other than localhost).

If so, if that server has and old version deployed, it may be hot code pushing old client code when your mobile app starts up!